# Using await outside of an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I was attempting to chain two async functions together, because the first had a conditional return parameter that caused the second to either run, or exit the module. However, I've found odd behavior I can't find in the specs.

```
async function isInLobby() {
    //promise.all([chained methods here])
    let exit = false;
    if (someCondition) exit = true;
}
```

This is a bastardized snippet of my code (you can see the full scope [here](https://github.com/RUJodan/SourceUndead/blob/master/routes/lobby.js#L53)), that simply checks if a player if already in a lobby, but that's irrelevant.

Next we have this async function.

```
async function countPlayer() {
    const keyLength = await scardAsync(game);
    return keyLength;
}
```

This function doesn't need to run if `exit === true`.

I tried to do

```
const inLobby = await isInLobby();
```

This I hoped would await to results, so I can use `inLobby` to conditionally run `countPlayer`, however I received a typeerror with no specific details.

Why can't you `await` an `async` function outside of the scope of the function? I know it's a sugar promise, so it must be chained to `then` but why is it that in `countPlayer` I can await another promise, but outside, I can't `await` `isInLobby`?

Comment: Can you show us *where* you did `await isInLobby()`, and how `inLobby` is used? Also, where/how is `countPlayer` called?

Comment: @Bergi I linked my repo for the actual context. Too much code to put into the question

Comment: I don't see where the problem is with that (maybe you already updated the repo)? If you refer to the `isInLobby().then( … countPlayer().then …` part, the solution is trivial: just make the function in which those calls are contained (the `(req, res) =>` one) `async`.

Comment: @Bergi the issue is not that it was broken, it works as is. I just didn't understand why top-level awaiting wasn't a thing. Turns out it's just not existent yet without scoping your entire module as an async function

Comment: But you don't even need *top-level* `await` for your code at all? That's why I wondered that you accepted the answer that doesn't really relate to the problem in the question.

Comment: Well, the question was "Why can't you await an async function outside of the scope of the function?" so I believed it to be relevant, I think.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Top level `await` is not supported. There are a few discussions by the standards committee on why this is, such as [this Github issue](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/9).

There's also a [thinkpiece on Github](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/0b6f317657f5167663b493c722647221) about why top level await is a bad idea. Specifically he suggests that if you have code like this:

```
// data.js
const data = await fetch( '/data.json' );
export default data;
```

Now **any** file that imports `data.js` won't execute until the fetch completes, so all of your module loading is now blocked. This makes it very difficult to reason about app module order, since we're used to top level Javascript executing synchronously and predictably. If this were allowed, knowing when a function gets defined becomes tricky.

**My perspective** is that it's bad practice for your module to have side effects simply by loading it. That means any consumer of your module will get side effects simply by requiring your module. This badly limits where your module can be used. A top level `await` probably means you're reading from some API or calling to some service at **load time.** Instead you should just export async functions that consumers can use at their own pace.

Comment: That's a good link, thank you. It's a shame top level support isn't there. I hope it is. Currently as it stands I have to nest my promises here and that is very bad practice and I don't like it. :( Thank you.

Comment: @SterlingArcher alternatively, use an async IIFE: `void async function() { const inLobby = await isInLobby() }()`

Comment: @robertklep wouldn't that scope `inLobby` to the function making it non-accessible?

Comment: @SterlingArcher yes it would, it would require you to move _all_ your code there (basically making it the "top level"). It's just an alternative to using `.then()` (sorry, should have made that a bit more clear).

Comment: dont agree, user of data.js is 'blocked' nevertheless while loading data.js itself and all of its dependencies, this notion of 'blocking' is not bad by itself. top level await could be considered as loading some dependency which one appearntly needs to have before usage is 'released'.

Comment: This is no longer true. Top-level await is [supported in Chrome and Firefox](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_await_top_level) and Safari 15 and NodeJS.

Comment: In my case, I am using dynamic import which I think is a valid use case.

Answer (score 203):

There is always this of course:

```
(async () => {
    await ...

    // all of the script.... 

})();
// nothing else
```

This makes a quick function with async where you can use await. It saves you the need to make an async function which is great! //credits Silve2611

Comment: Please elaborate further and explain why this works.

Comment: it is very stupid to Downvote this answer. It Makes a quick function with async where you can use await. It saves you the need to make an async function which is great!

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem since you still need to `await` this anonymous function, which again, doesn't work from outside of functions.

Comment: so how would this handle an error condition? does it also land inside the await code?

Comment: Tks this is greate help, specially to callback promise once fetch login API,  which is reponse back perfectly  to get storage getItem

Comment: @Silve2611 I'm really late, but basically, it creates an anonymous async function and executes it. It pretty much defines a function and runs it, using arrow function syntax

Comment: This kind of function in Javascript/Node is called  IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Keep in mind that this functions will be serial only in its own body, nothing in the code will care about awaiting the end of execution of this piece of code. I only use this on the entrypoint of my applications.

Answer (score 25):

As of Node.js [`14.3.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V14.md#support-for-top-level-await), the top-level await is supported with a flag:

```
--experimental-top-level-await
```

As of Node.js [`16.12.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V16.md#2021-10-20-version-16120-current-richardlau) / [`17.0.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V17.md#2021-10-19-version-1700-current-bethgriggs), no flag required.

Further details: https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

you can do top level await since typescript 3.8
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#-top-level-await
From the post:
This is because previously in JavaScript (along with most other languages with a similar feature), await was only allowed within the body of an async function. However, with top-level await, we can use await at the top level of a module.

```
const response = await fetch("...");
const greeting = await response.text();
console.log(greeting);

// Make sure we're a module
export {};
```

Note there’s a subtlety: top-level await only works at the top level of a module, and files are only considered modules when TypeScript finds an import or an export. In some basic cases, you might need to write out export {} as some boilerplate to make sure of this.

Top level await may not work in all environments where you might expect at this point. Currently, you can only use top level await when the target compiler option is es2017 or above, and module is esnext or system. Support within several environments and bundlers may be limited or may require enabling experimental support.

Comment: This is true of vanilla JavaScript as well. In node, you'll want to make sure you have `"type": "module"` at the top of your `package.json`, _**or**_ use the `.jsm` file extension.

Comment: `.jsm` has never been a valid file extension. It's `.mjs`.