# struggle to wrap promise with async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got unexpected identifier but not sure what is the mistake. I'm using fetch which is already a promise.

```
async getUsers = () => {
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(response => response.json())

  return resp
}

getUsers().then(users => console.log(users))
```

Comment: What is the output of this code? Does the console.log never fire or does it fire with an incorrect value?

Comment: @GabrielLovetro no output, it says unexpected identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the position of the `async` keyword:

Not:

```
async getUsers = () => {
```

But:

```
getUsers = async () => {
```

Run:

```js
getUsers = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
  return resp;
};

getUsers().then(users => console.log(users))
```

As per comments:

> Should I chain `then()` in `getUsers()`? `async`/`await` suppose to eliminate `then()` am I right?

Yes, you can `await` any `Promise`. Or use both `.then()` sometimes and `await` at others (like does the code above). But you could *just*  use `async`/`await` as well.

The example below uses no `.then()`:

```js
getUsers = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  return resp.json();
};

(async () => {
  // notice to use the await keyword, the code must be wrapped in an async function
  const users = await getUsers();
  console.log(users);
})();
```

Comment: oh that's a careless mistake! good spot! one question should I chain then() in getUsers()? Async/await suppose to eliminate then() am I right?

Comment: Yes, you don't *have* to chain. You can use `async`/`await` there as well (and any other `Promise`, for what is worth).

Comment: @SharonChai i would stick with either `async/await` or `then/catch`. Neither is wrong, however mixing them looks a bit weird :-) *Personal opinion:* use `async/await`, since it's just easier to read. Check the answer below by alex dykyi for a version of it

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the typo in the async word pointed by @acdcjunior, you're mixing `async / await` with the usual promise handling (`.then()`) which is not wrong but kind of defeats the point. Using only `async / await` would look like:

```js
const getUsers = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  return resp.json(); 
}

async function fetchUsers() {
    try {
        const users = await getUsers();
        console.log(users);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

fetchUsers();
```

Comment: an async function just returns a promise by default. `(async () => true)().then(res => console.log(res === true))` will result in `true`

Comment: also: you can't use await outside of an async function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679505/using-await-outside-of-an-async-function

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more explicit about the context where you use await. That was an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

you have the syntax wrong:

```
const getusers = async () => {
  ...
}
```

*`const` is optional*

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax of declaring your function is wrong, here's some explanation.

If `getUsers` is a method of a react component class the syntax should be :

```
  getUsers = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    ).then(response => response.json());
    return resp;
  };
```

or :

```
  async getUsers() {
    const resp = await fetch(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    ).then(response => response.json());
    return resp;
  };
```

If it's outside of a react component class or in a stateless arrow function component you can use this syntax :

```
  const getUsers = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    ).then(response => response.json());
    return resp;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
      const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
   
      return resp.json();
  } catch(e) {
     console.error(e)
  }  
}

(async () => {
   const users = await getUsers();
   console.log(users)
})()
```

Use this, and run

Comment: what you need to use `let resp` not `const resp`?. Isn't it easier to just return it?

Comment: @SharonChai if you want use const, see here example
const resp = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(res => res.json() )
You have 2 choises only in this case:
1. Use const with Promise.then;
2. Use async/await with let definition or with creating new variable;
Make sense?

Comment: so you removed `let` in your answer? now it looks better.