# How to have sweetalert return true/false for confirm without promise?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I like the simplicity of `javascript` confirm so that I can do this:

```
if(!confirm("are you sure?"))
    return;
```

in `sweetalert` you have to nest your `true` code within a `then` promise function.

Is there a way to have `sweetalert` return `true/false` the same way it happens in JS confirm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By design, [SweetAlert uses Promises](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises) to keep track of how the user interacts with the HTML-based alert and **it's non-blocking** *(you can still interact with the webpage/UI)* as opposed to the browser's built-in [**`confirm()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method, which, when displaying the modal window,  **it prevents the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed**.

---

You **cannot** call [**`swal()`**](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started) with the same interface-blocking behavior, as if it were another type of `confirm()`. **However**, by using the ES2017 [**`async`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[**`await`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) features, **you can write your code in a similar fashion and practically achieve the same goal** without blocking the interface.

---

In order to be able to use `async`/`await` across browsers, use a transpiler *(e.g. [**Babel**](https://babeljs.io))* to transpile/convert your source code with [**ES2015+ features**](https://devhints.io/es6) to [**ES5**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla), which is [**widely supported**](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es5):

#### - Using `swal()` in an `if` statement without wrapping:

You can just simply call `swal(...)` with `await`:

```
if (!await swal({text: 'Are you sure?', buttons: true})) {
    return;
}
```

And the `Promise` will resolve, when using SweetAlert as [**truthy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) *(`true`, when the user confirms the alert)* or [**falsy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) *(`null` otherwise)* as the condition of the `if` statement as described in the [**SweetAlert guides**](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises).

---

#### - Using `swal()` in an `if` statement with a wrapper to resemble to `confirm()`:

In order to provide the familiarity of `confirm()`, separate `swal(...)` with the desired options into an [**`async function`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function confirm(message) {
    return swal({
        text: message,
        buttons: true
    });
}
```

Then use it in the `if` statement prefixed with `await` as if it were just like a form of `confirm()` and as such, it would also work as expected:

```
if (!await confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    return;
}
```

---

#### Things to consider:

- Using `await` outside of an `async function` is [**currently not supported**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679505/using-await-outside-of-an-async-function). To get around this issue, either place your code in an event handler:

  ```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
      // ... await and other async code here
  });
  ```

  or use an `async` [`IFEE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) or [`IIAFE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745153/es8-immediately-invoked-async-function-expression):

  ```
  (async () => {
      // ... await and other async code here
  })();
  ```
- In order to easily transpile your source code containing ES2015+ features, **consider using a tool or library to bundle your code** *(e.g. [**Webpack**](https://webpack.js.org/), [**Browserify**](http://browserify.org/), [**Gulp**](https://gulpjs.com/), [**Grunt**](https://gruntjs.com/), etc.)* without much effort in the long run.

---

#### Working example with quick setup:

You can check out the sources of the working example in [**this repository**](https://github.com/richardszkcs/so-sample-sweetalert-es2017) based on [**Webpack**](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/).

*Full disclosure: I made the repository in order to provide an easily usable example, which can be cloned, install dependencies via NPM and start using right away.*

---

**Additional resources:**

- [**the `confirm()` method in the HTML Living Standard**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-confirm)
- [**the ES2017 Language Specification**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/)

Answer (score 3):

Using sweetalert2 v7.24.1

A work-around that might be handy.

**The Function**

```
function sweetConfirm(title, message, callback) {
    swal({
        title: title,
        text: message,
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true
    }).then((confirmed) => {
        callback(confirmed && confirmed.value == true);
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
sweetConfirm('Confirm action!', 'Are you sure?', function (confirmed) {
    if (confirmed) {
        // YES
    }
    else {
        // NO
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working btw, you'll get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function eventually.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved with a callback:

```
function confirm(question, text, callback) {
 swal({
   title: question,
   text: text,
   buttons: true
  }).then((confirmed) => {
     if (confirmed) {
        callback();
      }
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using with Form submit event

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="confirmFormAlert(this); return false">
...
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const confirmFormAlert = async function (form) {
    const sweetConfirm = await swal({
        title: "Confirm",
        buttons: true
    });
    if (sweetConfirm) {
        form.submit();
    }
    return sweetConfirm;
}
```