# Using two await in an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to return a value from two async functions. I am trying the method used in this thread.
[Using await outside of an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679505/using-await-outside-of-an-async-function)

However, I am always getting an undefined value.

```
common.loggedInUserisAdmin().then((currentUser) => {
   console.log(currentUser); // This line is executed before values return from loggedInUserisAdmin function.
});

// Here is my async functions code.
async loggedInUserisAdmin() {
  (async () => {
    await 
       this.getCurrentAccount().then().then((currentUser) => {
         this.getUserDetailsByEmail(currentUser.userName).then((userData) => {
          return userData.admin;
      })
   })
 })();
},

async getCurrentAccount() {
    return await msalApp.getAccount();
},

async getUserDetailsByEmail() {
    const dataUrl = `$https://localhost:12345/User/GetUserDetails?emailAddress=${emailAddress}`
    const errorMessage = 'Error getting current user'
    return await authorisedFetch(dataUrl, errorMessage)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see following problems in your code:

- You have mixed up `async-await` syntax with promise chaining.
- Value returned from a callback function isn't the return value of the outer `loggedInUserisAdmin` method.
- Also not sure what is the purpose of having an async IIFE inside an async method.

Your `loggedInUserisAdmin` method can be simplified as shown below:

```
async loggedInUserisAdmin() {
  const currentUser = await this.getCurrentAccount();
  const userData = await this.getUserDetailsByEmail(currentUser.userName);

  return userData.admin;
}
```

Make sure that code that calls this method has a `catch` block to catch and handle any errors that might occur during the execution of this method.

Answer (score 0):

After looking your code, it was easy identifying mistakes on mixing promises/async/await/then etc.
In fact, the code is easier to solve than you think.
In Promise.then((value) => {} ) you must keep chaining functions , but with await you will receive a value as result, and you have to store the result in a variable or constant. await turns your code sequential, instead of chaining functions on and on when using Promises.
Take a look at the fixed code below:

```
async loggedInUserisAdmin() {
   const currentUser = await this.getCurrentAccount();
   const userData = await this.getUserDetailsByEmail(currentUser.userName)
   return userData.admin
}
```

Behind the scenes, node compiler/interpreter is doing magic with state machines and several management in order to turn possible our code be simple.
Making our lives easier.