# why is variable players and currentPlayer undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am setting a variable to be the returned value from a function, players and currentPlayer, however it is saying that variable is undefined when trying to use in another function? is the way I'm setting the variable wrong?

```
let message = document.getElementById('game-message');
// async allows the use of the "await" keyword
async function setPlayers() {
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player One?</p>`;
    let player1 = await getUserInput();
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player Two</p>`;
    let player2 = await getUserInput();
    const players = [];
    players.push(player1, player2);
    return players;
}

var players = setPlayers();
var currentPlayer = players[0];
```

Comment: you do not await it. `const players = await setPlayers();`

Comment: @Sheri are you sure about that?

Comment: @epascarello I have tried adding the await but getting this error message - Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71517624/because-i-cant-run-await-on-the-top-level-i-have-to-put-it-into-an-async-funct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then warp it in [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked function expression) because you need to put `await` when calling `setPlayers` function, so to use `await`, the parent function must be an async function.

```
let message = document.getElementById('game-message');
// async allows the use of the "await" keyword
async function setPlayers() {
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player One?</p>`;
    let player1 = await getUserInput();
    message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player Two</p>`;
    let player2 = await getUserInput();
    const players = [];
    players.push(player1, player2);
    return players;
}

let players, currentPlayer; # declare variables here
(async() => {
    # now assigning values to the variables
    players = await setPlayers();
    currentPlayer = players[0];
})()

# now you can access those variables here
console.log(players, currentPlayer)
```

Comment: I need to store players and current players as global variables. Is there a way around it at all?

Comment: yes you can, i have update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pollute the global namespace if you can help it. Try writing code that is self contained or a javascript module. If you need to communicate between namespaces, then an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) with [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) can be used to share data.

```js
// Global namespace
if ( !window.myGameEvents ) window.myGameEvents = new EventTarget();

// Game namespace 
(async() => {
    // Game Global Variables
    const message = document.getElementById('game-message');
    const players = [];
    let currentPlayer = null;

    // Game Methods
    async function setPlayers(){
        message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player One?</p>`;
        players[0] = await getUserInput();

        message.innerHTML = `<p>Name of player Two</p>`;
        players[1] = await getUserInput();
    }

    async function getUserInput(){
        /* ...code... */
    }

    /* ...code... */

    // Game Run
    await setPlayers();
    currentPlayer = players[0];

    // Sample Event Dispatch
    myGameEvents.dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent('my-event-name',{
        detail: { /* ...data... */ }
    }) )
})();
```