# How can I wait for an image to download Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, async-await, download

Using Nodejs and image-downloader. I am trying to run a compiler function at the end after all the images have downloaded. The imageDownload function gets triggered multiple times. The console.log('Saved to', filename); runs way after everything.

```
import {image} from 'image-downloader';
await imageDownload ('https://syntheticnews.com/wpcontent/uploads/2023/12/Kodiak_Defense_1-1024x683.jpg');

export async function imageDownload (url) {
  var options={
    url: url,
    dest: `../../testimage.jpg`,  
  };
        
  image(options)
    .then(({ filename }) => {
      console.log('Saved to', filename);     
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

console.log ("This will be the next function and should run after the save to filename log");
```

The await on the function call just seems to await the running of the code not the downloading of the file. I really need an await on the .then statement but that doesn't work :).  Is there a better way than watching the folder and await the files expected?

Comment: Your `imageDownload` function doesn't return anything, so your `await imageDownload()` has nothing to wait for. (Also, don't use `var` in modern JS, use `let` or `const`. The scoping rules for `var` are exotic enough that you should leave it in the past).

Comment: Please refactor the code and share the piece of sample code on how you want to use it

Answer (score 0):

await waits for promises to be resolved or rejected. In the above code, the `image` function returns a promise but the wrapper function `imageDownload` is not returning the promise returned by the `image` function.

Read this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Try this code -

```
import { image } from 'image-downloader';
await imageDownload('https://syntheticnews.com/wpcontent/uploads/2023/12/Kodiak_Defense_1-1024x683.jpg');

export async function imageDownload(url) {
    var options = {
        url: url,
        dest: `../../testimage.jpg`,
    };

    return image(options)
        .then(({ filename }) => {
            console.log('Saved to', filename);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}

console.log("This will be the next function and should run after the save to filename log");
```

Although above code works, I would recommend not using await directly in a file - [Using await outside of an async function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39679505/using-await-outside-of-an-async-function)

Comment: I am trying a different way. I will let you know if it fixes my issue. I have to change the input a little for the next function 
`code` import {image} from 'image-downloader';


await imageDownload ('https://syntheticnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Kodiak_Defense_1-1024x683.jpg');

export async function imageDownload (url) {

        var options={
          url: url,
          dest: `../../testimage.jpg`,  
        };
        
        let filename = await image(options)
         
        console.log ("This should run after the save to filename log", filename);

Comment: I also don't know how to put code into a comment :). I will answer the with the code if it works.